# Best way to download files simultaneously with Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, download, python-requests

I'm trying to send simultaneous `get` requests with the Python `requests` module.

While searching for a solution I've come across lots of different approaches, including `grequests`, `gevent.monkey`, `requests futures`, `threading`, `multi-processing`...

I'm a little overwhelmed and not sure which one to pick, regarding speed and code-readibility.

The task is to download < 400 files as fast as possible, all from the same server. Ideally it should output the status for the downloads in terminal, e. g. print an error or success message per request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def download(webpage):
    requests.get(webpage)
    # Whatever else you need to do to download your resource, put it in here

urls = ['https://www.example.com', 'https://www.google.com','https://yahoo.com'] # Populate with resources you wish to download
threads = {}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in urls:
        print(i)
        threads[i] = threading.Thread(target=download, args=(i,))
    for i in threads:
        threads[i].start()
    for i in threads:
        threads[i].join()
    print('successfully done.')
```

The above code contains a function called `download` that represents whatever code you have to run to download the resource you're looking to download. Then a list is made populated with urls you wish to download - change these values as you please. This is assembled in to a second dictionary that contains the threads. This is so that you can have as many urls in the url dictionary as you want, and a separate thread is made for each of them. The threads are each started, then joined.

Answer (score 0):

I would use **threading** as it is not necessary to run the downloads on multiple cores like multiprocessing does.
So write a function where `requests.get()` is in it and then start as a thread.
But remember that your internet connection has to be fast enough, otherwise it wouldn't be worth it.